# Not rendering element after setState

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, virtual-dom

I have a personal hook which is used to manage a list of counters:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { db } from "../services/database";

const useCounters = () => {
  const [counters, setCounters] = useState([]);
  console.log("Hook", counters);

  const addCounter = async (newCounter) => {
    try {
      await db.cards.add(newCounter);
      setCounters((prevState) => [...prevState, newCounter]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const removeCounter = async (idToRemove) => {
    try {
      await db.cards.delete(idToRemove);
      setCounters(counters.filter((counter) => counter.id !== idToRemove));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const updateCounter = async (idToUpdate, newValue) => {
    try {
      await db.cards.update(idToUpdate, { value: newValue });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = async () => {
      db.cards.toArray().then((cards) => {
        setCounters(cards);
      });
    };
    loadData();
  }, []);

  return {
    counters,
    addCounter,
    removeCounter,
    updateCounter,
  };
};

export default useCounters;
```

And I have an element that is responsible for rendering these counters:

```
import Counter from "../components/Counter";
import AddCounter from "../components/AddCounter.js";
import Sleep from "../components/Sleep";

import useCounters from "../Hooks/useCounters";

import Style from "../css/pages/cards.module.css";

const Cards = () => {
  const { counters } = useCounters();
  console.log("Cards", counters);

  return (
    <div className={Style.cards}>
      {counters.map((item) => (
        <Counter
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          title={item.title}
          initial={item.initialValue}
          value={item.value}
          color={item.color}
        />
      ))}
      <AddCounter />
      <Sleep />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cards;
```

My problem is that when using the methods that manipulate the counters, it updates the state of the counters, but it does not render this in the cards component. Can someone explain to me what is happening and how to fix?

--

I tried to put 'counters' as a useEffect dependency but this generates an infinite rendering (eternal loop).

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = async () => {
      db.cards.toArray().then((cards) => {
        setCounters(cards);
      });
    };
    loadData();
  }, [counters]);
```

Comment: can you share the snippet where you are calling  addCounter,
    removeCounter,
    updateCounter,?

Comment: Here is the repository on github [link](https://github.com/dev-rafaelmachado/RPG-Controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is that your `counters` state is not a global state, but a local state in **every** component that uses your hook.

For example: If you use the hook in `Cards` and in `AddCounter` **both components have a local version of that state**. If you add a counter in `AddCounter` the `counters` variable there will change, but not in the `Cards` component. Have a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-jepsen-87jiuc) to see this behaviour.

If you want to share your state between components, there are several ways:

1. [Lift the state up](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components) and pass it down via props
2. Use the [context api](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) provided by react
3. Use a state management solution like Redux or Zustand

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm beginner in React, I've been stuck on this for a while, thanks again